# Best way to implement a multilingual application in silverlight and WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, multilingual

I have always been interested in how should I implement a multilingual applications and what or which way I should go to deal with this and also what's the best way to control the layouts in application scope? I've read many articles but the more read, the more confused I get. I want to know Is there any standard pattern to implement application such as this.

Any advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found [Location using MarkupExtension](http://www.wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html) the best way to do localization in WPF and I also have successfully used it in one of my WPF projects.

It allows you to change the language of whole application at run-time. You can allow user to select and change language at run-time without requiring user to restart the app.

Comment: Thank you Haris, was a Great tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently developing a multilingual application, these links helped me a lot:

[WPF Globalization and Localization Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx)
[WPF Localization Guidance](http://wpflocalization.codeplex.com/)
IMO working with BAML is very painful instead I'm using [WPF localization extension](http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/) now, It's very good library and very easy to use.